# how can i include style sheet?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want use stylesheet dynamically.but still getting error.
can you help me please..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
......

    <xsl:param name="temp"/>   
 <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="temp=true">
                <include href="library.xsl"/>


            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <include href="C:\Users\..\Desktop\library.xsl"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
<xsl:template match="/catalog">
....
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, as includes and imports are resolved statically (typically at the point where the processor compiles the stylesheet into its internal representation).  As [the spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets):

> The `xsl:include` element is only allowed as a top-level element

i.e. it has to be directly inside the `xsl:stylesheet`, it can't be nested inside anything else.

Comment: any other way to include  stylesheet with param?

Comment: @natalia not really, because by the time the processing stage starts and you can access parameter values, the includes will already have been resolved.  You'll need to have two different stylesheets for the different cases and handle the condition externally (being XML, those two stylesheets could of course be generated from a template using XSLT rather than you having to maintain them both by hand).